# Scilab syntax: How to transpose and reshape without the use of an intermediate variable?

Tags: syntax, scilab

Lets use the matrix A as an example:

```
-->A = [1 2 3; 4 5 6]
 A  =

    1.    2.    3.  
    4.    5.    6.
```

I can transpose this matrix:

```
-->A'
 ans  =

    1.    4.  
    2.    5.  
    3.    6.
```

...and I can reshape this matrix into a single column:

```
-->A(:)
 ans  =

    1.  
    4.  
    2.  
    5.  
    3.  
    6.
```

...but I cannot transpose and reshape in a single line or without using a intermediate variable:

```
-->A'(:)
     !--error 276 
Missing operator, comma, or semicolon.

-->B = A'; B(:)
 ans  =

    1.  
    2.  
    3.  
    4.  
    5.  
    6.
```

Is there a way to accomplish this without the intermediate variable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although the transpose operator doesn't seem to have a keyword equivalent the `(:)` syntax does: [matrix](http://help.scilab.org/docs/5.3.1/en_US/matrix.html).

So the equivalent of `A(:)` would be `matrix(A,1,-1)` such that you're reshaping to 1 column and 'however many' rows (the -1 argument). Thus if you feed `A'` into that you get the row vector in the desired order

```
-->matrix(A',1,-1)
 ans  =

    1.    2.    3.    4.    5.    6.
```

This works with the conjugate transpose operator too (`A.'`).

Comment: Thanks, this is how I ended up coding it, too. I still think there must be a 'better' way (less typing, clearer, not with a workaround feeling).